# Design pattern to editor of templates in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, design-patterns

I have a service in Spring that reads a template written/edited by user and with fields and entities existing in template (edited by user) are return the results of this template. Example: `{{ user.name }}`, in this case `user` are a entity and `name` is a field written by user, follow example, the question is what best design pattern to this service ? for the better organized. Most specifically​ in service class https://github.com/RenanPalmeira/spring-demo/blob/client-jinjava/src/main/java/com/renanpalmeira/jinjava/service/RenderService.java

https://github.com/renanpalmeira/spring-demo/tree/client-jinjava

Note: `{{entity.field}}` the entity represent a endpoint, this service is a big client of an API

Comment: you need an engine to resolving the variable trees. e.g: `{user:{name: string, address:{country:string, city:string}}}`

Comment: @holi-java Ok... I used jinjava for this... My problem is to write relationship between the entities in template and what's  endpoint is this entity... In my example, I using retrofit and for this relationship between entities and endpoint I used a enum class

Comment: https://github.com/RenanPalmeira/spring-demo/blob/client-jinjava/src/main/java/com/renanpalmeira/jinjava/domain/GithubEndpoints.java

Comment: most template engine supports primitives,`String` . so the endpoint is primitives and `String`. in the server side you need resolving the variable trees. in the client side you need a Checker to checking the expression whether is the endpoint expression or not with variable trees that generated by the server.

Comment: @holi-java Ok, but my code already does this... First I match/search in template (with regex) the entities (this is a utility class), second I get the entities found in template and use enum class to did filter the entities found and forEach the entities remaining I call request with retrofit (I keep the entities and relationship in enum)

Comment: well, what is your problem? and you need put the class diagram to show the relationships between them in your question.

Comment: @holi-java my problem is the implementation... My code is little strange with use a enum class and separate retrofit interface (with just one method)

Comment: @holi-java thanks for tip... Now I'm going to draw diagram !

Comment: @holi-java [class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqct9.png)

Comment: Indeed,you need a `TemplateEngine` to load a `Template` with a `Context`, let the `Context` to checking each expression whether is vaild or not.then `Template` can checking all expression is valid or not. A `Context` which generate variables tree that a `Template` can taking. In this way, your `Context` is indepent from your `Template` module, then you can providing any template language that supports cheching the expression is valid or not. The diffs between diff template language is:"**How to extract the expressions in a certain template, e.g:*.vm, *.ftl, *.thtml?**"

Comment: @holi-java I understand :D but when I get variables from context, and pass to retrofit (and get entities relationship between variables from my enum class) in this way https://github.com/RenanPalmeira/spring-demo/blob/client-jinjava/src/main/java/com/renanpalmeira/jinjava/service/RenderService.java#L54-L74

Comment: @holi-java my enum class https://github.com/RenanPalmeira/spring-demo/blob/client-jinjava/src/main/java/com/renanpalmeira/jinjava/domain/GithubEndpoints.java

Comment: What is your problem? You need describe your problem exactly.

Comment: @holi-java my problem was implementation , I was thinking use enum class in this case was little strange... but after your comments and other response of my question, this code is OK... thanks for helping